# A component required a bean named 'userService' that could not be found. Is there any dependency for this error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
@Resource(name = "userService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Autowired and Qualifier annotation. Qualifier takes the bean name.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("userService")
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
```